# How to list python code import order as a tree?

Tags: python, python-import

As I am often refactoring python libraries or cli-tools, I often need to build a graph of how imports happen and in which order when a command is executed.

Mainly i want to dump a tree-like listing on the command line in order to see these imports, as imports would obviously repeat, it would need to ignore 2nd hand imports or the tree would be too hard to read.

I seen some pypi projects that can print dependencies in such way, like pipdeptree but this works only for package dependencies, not imports, which as quite different.

In fact in my case I am interested only about internal imports, so I would want to exclude imports from external package when I do such a listing.

Example of desired output in case foo library import foo.cli from `__init__` and `cli` module imports `logging` and `utils` modules:

```
- foo
  - foo.cli
    - foo.logging
    - foo.utils
```